# Error running a scrape command ruby on rails

Tags: web-scraping, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to re-setup my app on a new computer and run a scrape to build the database. When I run my first rake scraper:scrape, this is the error I am getting. I am not sure why I am getting this error any help would make my day.. cheers!

```
Art West@ARTWESTIV ~/desktop/duckduckjeep-master
$ rake scraper:scrape --trace
** Invoke scraper:scrape (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute scraper:scrape
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
c:/Users/Art West/desktop/duckduckjeep-master/lib/tasks/scraper.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
c:/Users/Art West/desktop/duckduckjeep-master/lib/tasks/scraper.rake:12:in `loop'
c:/Users/Art West/desktop/duckduckjeep-master/lib/tasks/scraper.rake:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => scraper:scrape
```

here is my scraper.rake

```
namespace :scraper do
  desc "Fetch Craigslist posts from 3Taps"
  task scrape: :environment do
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'json'
    # Set API token and URL
    auth_token = "b077632d17da8857e2fa92c053115e43"
    polling_url = "http://polling.3taps.com/poll"

  # Grab data until up-to-date
    loop do

    # Specify request parameters
    params = {
      auth_token: auth_token,
      anchor: Anchor.first.value,
      source:"CRAIG",
      category_group: "VVVV",
      category: "VAUT",
      'location.country' => "USA",
      retvals: "location,external_url,heading,body,timestamp,price,images,annotations"

    }

    # Prepare API request
    uri = URI.parse(polling_url)
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

    # Submit request
    result = JSON.parse(open(uri).read)

    # Display results to screen
    #puts result["postings"].first["annotations"]["year"]

    Anchor.first.update(value: result["anchor"])
    puts Anchor.first.value
    break if result["postings"].empty?

    # #store results in Database
    result["postings"].each do |posting|

      #ADD HARD FILTER (IN PROGRESS....)
      if posting["annotations"]["make"] == "Jeep"

        #create new post
        @post= Post.new
        @post.heading = posting["heading"]
        @post.body = posting["body"]
        @post.price = posting["price"]
        @post.neighborhood = posting["location"]["locality"]
        @post.external_url = posting["external_url"]
        @post.timestamp = posting["timestamp"]
        @post.year = posting ["annotations"]["year"] if posting ["annotations"]["year"].present? 
        @post.make = posting ["annotations"]["make"] if posting ["annotations"]["make"].present? 
        @post.model = posting ["annotations"]["model"] if posting ["annotations"]["model"].present? 
        @post.title_status = posting ["annotations"]["title_status"] if posting ["annotations"]["title_status"].present? 
        @post.transmission = posting ["annotations"]["transmission"] if posting ["annotations"]["transmission"].present? 
        @post.mileage = posting ["annotations"]["mileage"] if posting ["annotations"]["mileage"].present? 
        @post.source_account = posting ["annotations"]["source_account"] if posting ["annotations"]["source_account"].present?
        @post.phone = posting ["annotations"]["phone"] if posting ["annotations"]["phone"].present?
        @post.lat = posting["location"]["lat"]
        @post.lng = posting["location"]["long"]
        @post.zipcode = posting["location"]["zipcode"]
        #Save Post
        @post.save

        # Loop over images and save to Image database
        posting["images"].each do |image|
          @image = Image.new
          @image.url = image["full"]
          @image.post_id = @post.id 
          @image.save
        end
      end

    end
    end
  end




desc "Destroy All Posting Data"
task destroy_all_posts: :environment do
  Post.destroy_all
end

desc "Save neighborhood codes in a reference table"
task scrape_neighborhoods: :environment do
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'json'

      # Set API token and URL
      auth_token = "b077632d17da8857e2fa92c053115e43"
      location_url = "http://reference.3taps.com/locations"

    # Specify request parameters
    params = {
      auth_token: auth_token,
      level: "locality",
      country: "USA"
    }


# Prepare API request
uri = URI.parse(location_url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

    # Submit request
    result = JSON.parse(open(uri).read)

    # Display results to screen
    # puts JSON.pretty_generate result
    
    # Store results in database
    result["locations"].each do |location|
      @location = Location.new
      @location.code = location["code"]
      @location.name = location["short_name"]
      @location.save
    end
  end




  desc "Discard old data"
  task discard_old_data: :environment do
    Post.all.each do |post|
      if post.created_at < 72.hours.ago
        post.destoy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is saying it all:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
```

You are trying to call `value` on `nil` at some point. And, this is probably happening here:

```
# Specify request parameters
params = {
  auth_token: auth_token,
  anchor: Anchor.first.value, # this is the line that's creating problem
  source:"CRAIG",
  category_group: "VVVV",
  category: "VAUT",
  'location.country' => "USA",
  retvals: "location,external_url,heading,body,timestamp,price,images,annotations"

}
```

When you call this: `anchor: Anchor.first.value` for the very first time, your `Anchor.first` is `nil` and so you are trying to call: `nil.value` and that's where your rake task fails with the specified error message.

Make sure you have populated the database table (`anchors`) so that when you call `Anchor.first`, you don't get `nil`.

Another approach to avoid this issue would be to use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try):

```
  anchor: Anchor.first.try(:value)
```

That way, your rake task won't fail even if `Anchor.first` returns `nil`.

Comment: Makes sense, how can I establish an anchor value?

Comment: You can populate the database with `anchors` element in several ways. e.g. you can do: `Anchor.create(attribute_1: value_1, attribute_2: value_2, ...)`